# How to access elasticsearch.yml?

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

How to access elasticsearch.yml?

According to this doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html , I can access the Settings in elastic.yml  .. . And once I access it, i want to check the value of "http.max_content_length" and change it if possible

ie. I have this sample curl command, how do I access it using this curl format?:

> curl -u admin:QWEREGRHFDSGER
>   'https://portal-ssl875-6.blahblah.....-1115de1b-f544-4432-8384-3a55b1b37954@sample.com:24332/

Comment: In my case elasticsearch.yml is in <install_directory>/config/elasticsearch.yml Do you have trouble finding this file ?

Comment: @pLOPeGG thanks. so I can do :

`curl -u admin:QWEREGRHFDSGER 'https://portal-ssl875-6.blahblah.....-1115de1b-f544-4432-8384-3a55b1b37954@sample.com:24332/<install_directory>/config/elasticsearch.yml`

And that should work? Sorry not really familiar with curl commands

Comment: curl is tool to tranfer data from or to a server. If you are running the elasticsearch server on your computer, just modify the file with an editor and restart the ES server. Else, you need to get on the machine running ES and do the modification. Maybe I'm wrong bur I don't see why you would use curl here.